# Make KnockoutJs bind all viewmodels to $Data by default

Tags: knockout.js

In my application I am doing this a lot

```
data-bind="handler:method.bind($data)"
```

because i want the this in the methods being called referencing the viewmodel that holds it. Is there any way to plug this into knockout such by default it always bind methods to the $data of current binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few thoughts/ideas:

- The `click` and `event` bindings will do this for you automatically. They will call the function with `this` being `$data` and pass `$data` as the first argument. I am not sure if you are using custom bindings or some other binding.
- You can often handle this in your view model itself by binding your functions there or depending on your preference/structure, you can capture the value of `this` in a variable.

  ```
  var ViewModel = function() {
     this.myMethod = function() {
         // use this
     }.bind(this);

      //or 

      var self = this;

      this.myMethod2 = function() {
          //use self instead of this inside your function
      };
  };
  ```
- The Knockout.punches [plugin](http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/) also will help maintain the correct value of this, such that if you do `data-bind="click: $parent.someFunction"` it will properly call the function with `$parent` as `this`.

Comment: Thanks. Can it be something with using prototypes ? I create my stuff with typescript. I have just gotten so use to always writing bind($data) in my bindings, so i dont even recall where exactly it didnt work when i started doign that. I will take a second look and see if click,event are done automaticly. or else give punches a try. thanks